# list of dictionaries, how to get: intersection based on one value and symmetric difference based on another value

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, list-comprehension

Lets say I have:

```
dict_listA = [
    {'id':0, 'b':1},
    {'id':1, 'b':2},
    {'id':2, 'b':3},
]
```

and

```
dict_listB = [
    {'id':1, 'b':1},
    {'id':2, 'b':3},
    {'id':3, 'b':2},
]
```

How would I get a list of the id's where we have the intersection of these based on 'id' but symmetric difference based on b?

```
same_a_different_b = [
    {'id':1, 'b':2},
]
```

currently this is my solution:

```
for d1 in list_dictA:
    same_a_different_b = filter(lambda d2: d2['id'] == d1['id'] and d2['b'] != d1['b'], list_dictB)
```

I ask because this is currently the biggest time-sink in my program, I wish there was some way of doing it quicker. The result (`same_a_different_b`) is usually 0 or very small, one list has about 900 entries and the other around 1400. It currently takes 9 seconds.

Comment: what's your python version?

Comment: It's Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
hashed = {e['id']: e['b'] for e in dict_listB}
same_a_different_b2 = [e for e in dict_listA if e['id'] in hashed and hashed[e['id']] != e['b']]
```

I think complexity of algorithm is equal to O(len(a) + len(b)).
For example in your solution it is equal to O(len(a) * len(b)).

If list can have duplicates:

```
hashed = defaultdict(set)
for e in dict_listB:
    hashed[e['id']].add(e['b'])
same_a_different_b2 = [e for e in dict_listA if e['id'] in hashed and e['b'] not in hashed[e['id']]]
```

Compare speed (len(a) == len(b) == 2000):

```
from collections import defaultdict

import time
from itertools import product

dict_listA = [
    {'id': 0, 'b': 1},
    {'id': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 2, 'b': 3},
    *[{'id': i, 'b': 1} for i in range(10000, 10000 + 2000)]
]

dict_listB = [
    {'id': 1, 'b': 1},
    {'id': 2, 'b': 3},
    {'id': 3, 'b': 2},
    *[{'id': i, 'b': 1} for i in range(20000, 20000 + 2000)]
]

same_a_different_b = [
    {'id': 1, 'b': 2},
]
start_time = time.clock()


def previous_solution():
    new_same_a_different_b = []
    for d1 in dict_listA:
        new_same_a_different_b.extend(filter(lambda d2: d2['id'] == d1['id'] and d2['b'] != d1['b'], dict_listB))
    return new_same_a_different_b


def new_solution():
    hashed = {e['id']: e['b'] for e in dict_listB}
    return [e for e in dict_listA if e['id'] in hashed and hashed[e['id']] != e['b']]


def other_solution():
    return [d1 for d1, d2 in product(dict_listA, dict_listB) if d2['id'] == d1['id'] and d2['b'] != d1['b']]


for func, name in [
    (previous_solution, 'previous_solution'),
    (new_solution, 'new_solution'),
    (other_solution, 'other_solution')
]:
    start_time = time.clock()
    new_result = func()
    print('{:20}: {:.5f}'.format(name, time.clock() - start_time))
    assert new_result, same_a_different_b
```

Results:

```
previous_solution   : 1.06517
new_solution        : 0.00073
other_solution      : 0.60582
```

Comment: You lose space efficiency with this solution, but I like it.

Comment: I must admit that I have a hard time fully understanding how you do it. How and why ``hashed``is created and how you utilize it (in ``hashed[e['id']]``). Think I have to read up a little bit on list comprehension and what magic you can do with it. Even though the readability might take a hit, I can't argue with the result. It now finishes in 0.034 seconds instead of 9 and for that I'm very thankful! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using list comprehension and `itertools.prodcut`:

```
In [41]: from itertools import product
In [42]: [d1 for d1, d2 in product(dict_listA, dict_listB) if d2['id'] == d1['id'] and d2['b'] != d1['b']]
Out[42]: [{'id': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

But note that this will generate duplicate results if you have multiple matched items within `dict_listB`. If you don't want to keep all the duplicate ones, you can use a set comprehension instead.

Comment: I like the readability of this one (even though I don't fully understand product), but it averaged on around 1.66 seconds versus the 0.034 of the other solution.